# Using AppleScript editor to input multiple commands in terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript

So i'm trying to write a simple script that opens terminal, ssh onto a server and does stuff while it's there.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    Activate
    do script "cd documents"
    delay 2
    do script "ssh private key user@server"
    delay 6
    do script "while true; do curl..."
end tell
```

How do i get it all in one terminal tab?
Currently it opens separate windows for each command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
    activate
    do script "echo \"commmand one\"" in window 1
    do script "echo \"commmand two\"" in window 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use semicolon to concatenate two commands, like this:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "echo \"commmand one\"" & " ; " & "echo \"commmand two\""
end tell
```

I used `&` symbol to demo concatenation in case the "echo \"commmand one\"" is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
    activate
    delay 1
    do script "cd ~/Projects" in front window
    do script "ls -al" in front window
    do script "date" in front window

    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    delay 1
    do script "cd ~/Projects/react-app" in front window
    do script "ls -al" in front window
end tell
```